# ASP ControlParameter references control outside web user control

Tags: asp.net, webusercontrol

I want to move asp code from a *web form* to a *web user control*. The code to migrate looks like this [microsfot code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.whereparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="SalesOrderHeader" runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="name=AdventureWorksEntities" 
  DefaultContainerName="AdventureWorksEntities" EnableDelete="True" 
  EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="SalesOrderHeader" 
  EntityTypeFilter="" OrderBy="it.TotalDue DESC" Select="" 
   Where="it.OnlineOrderFlag = TRUE AND it.TotalDue &gt; @ordercost">
  <WhereParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="costLimit" DbType="Int32" 
      DefaultValue="2500" Name="ordercost" PropertyName="Text" />
  </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Issue is than referenced control ( `costLimit` ) will remain in *web form*.

How can I do to reference `costLimit` from inside of *web user control* to *web form* container? If it is not possible, what is the most elegant workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible no, what you can do though is to pass the value on in your constructor of the newly created User Control and then bind the parameter to your `EntityDataSource` inside the constructor using server side code.

Comment: Thanks Jason, very useful answer. I will code it as you explain.